# Does ‘profile’ have a meaning of ‘identify’ or “read” by appearance?

Tags: meaning

Time magazine (July 16) carries Maya Angelou’s comment on the Zimmerman Trial under the title, “Maya Angelou reacts to Zimmerman Trial, evokes Civil Rights era.”
http://swampland.time.com/2013/07/16/maya-angelou-reacts-to-zimmerman-trial-evoking-civil-rights-era/#ixzz2ZFi70AgH

It goes as follows;

> “Author, poet, and activist Maya Angelou was shaken by the verdict of
>   the George Zimmerman trial, saying it shows “how far we have to go” as
>   a country. “That one man, armed with a gun can actually **profile** a
>   young man because he is black and end up shooting him dead…It is so
>   painful,” Angelou said in an interview with TIME Monday.”

According to Oxford Advanced Learners’ Dictionary, ‘profile’ as a verb is only defined as;

to give or write a description of sb / stg that gives most important information.

Does the word, “profiles” have the meanings such as “identify" or "read" by figure and appearance, which I construe from the text, other than the OALD’s definition? Is it a *prevailing* usage? What does ‘profile’ here mean specifically?

Comment: Angelou's usage is a relatively uncommon extension from [criminal profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offender_profiling) - *a behavioral and investigative tool that is intended to help investigators to accurately predict and profile the characteristics of **unknown** criminal subjects or offenders.* In her usage, the individual being profiled isn't unknown, obviously. What she means is Zimmerman ***classified*** his victim as "having the typical characteristics of a criminal". Or maybe "fitting Zimmerman's profile of a typical criminal, who should therefore be shot on sight".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a specific sense of *profile* meaning ‘to make assumptions about a person's intentions or behavior.’ It is widely used in discussions of crime and law enforcement. Angelou is arguing that Zimmerman assumed that Martin was a criminal on the basis of his skin color, an act known as [racial profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_profiling).

Comment: A _profile_ is also used for an expected set of characteristics. For example, _Everyone ran away because the oncoming pedestrian fit the profile of a suicide bomber._